# Как начать подготовку одного долгогрузящегося activity из предыдущего?

Tags: android, java

В проекте есть одно довольно-таки загруженное activity, создание которого занимает примерно 2 секунды. Можно ли как-то заставить приложение начать подготавливать это activity еще при старте приложения(при показе начального экрана), чтобы переход к тяжёлому activity произошёл мгновенно?

ОБНОВЛЕНО:
Почитал про AsyncTask, попробовал реализовать, но приложение крашится. Мне кажется, это из-за того, что я пытаюсь работать в doInBackground с еще не существующим activity, создавая на нём различные View...
Вот немного кода:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnClickListener{

    MyTask mt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mt = new MyTask();
        mt.execute();
    }
    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            MusicPerson1 activity;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
              super.onPreExecute();
              Log.d("mylog","onPreExecute begins");
            }

            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try{    
                Log.d("mylog","doInBackground begins");
                activity = new MusicPerson1();
                Log.d("mylog","CheckPoint 1");
                activity.setContentView(R.layout.musicperson1);
                Log.d("mylog","CheckPoint 2");
                HorizontalScrollView Scroll = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
            // создание LinearLayout
              LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(activity);
              LinearLayout linLayout1 = new LinearLayout(activity);
              LinearLayout linLayout2 = new LinearLayout(activity);
              LinearLayout linLayout3 = new LinearLayout(activity);
              // установим ориентацию
              linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
              linLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
              linLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
              linLayout3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
              // создаем LayoutParams  
              LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 
              LayoutParams linLayoutParam1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
              Scroll.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
              Scroll.addView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);
              linLayout.addView(linLayout1, linLayoutParam1);
              linLayout.addView(linLayout2, linLayoutParam1);
              linLayout.addView(linLayout3, linLayoutParam1);

              Log.d("mylog","CheckPoint 3");

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("mylog","Fucking NullPointerException");
              }
              return null;
            }
```

В логах отображается "onPreExecute begins" и "doInBackground begins", после чего приложение вылетает.
Ошибка:

```
11-18 19:53:21.924: E/AndroidRuntime(794): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-18 19:53:21.924: E/AndroidRuntime(794): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-18 19:53:21.924: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
```

И так далее...

Comment: Можно, и даже нужно. Загружать нужно в отдельном треде. Если долго в onCreate Activity что то делать, то может и исключение произойти (ANR). А вот как разбивать - это уже нужно думать.

Comment: то есть крашится в MusicPerson1().create()?
не помешало бы и его код выложить...

Comment: В MusicPerson1 метод OnCreate я вообще пустым оставил. Раньше весь код был в нём и норм работал, но долго грузился. Я перенес весь код в doInBackground с незначительными исправлениями...

Comment: Обычно долго грузится (если абстрагироваться от многопоточности) из-за того что на активити отображается туева хуча вьюшек, могу посоветовать использовать http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html позволяет сконструировать гуй и назначить его контентом активити, т.е. во время работы активити А вы создаете конечный вью который будет содержаться в активити Б, а при запуске активити Б ставите ему уже сконструированный контент.

Comment: хм а в чем проблема запустить асинктаск после запуска активити и потихоньку заполнять контентом?

Comment: Raskilas, а как можно передать этот LayoutInflater в другую activity? Пробовал с помощью intent.putExtra - не получается...

Answer (score 1):

Для оптимизации тяжелых Activity используется обычно [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html)

Это легкий **View** компонент, не имеющий размеров и он ничего не рисует на экране выполняя роль заглушки, заменяя собой дочерние элементы внутри родительской разметки.

Возможно ваша разметка чересчур перегружена тяжёлыми элементами и **ViewStub** позволяет разгрузить разметку представляя собой лёгкий элемент для отображения или сокрытия в иерархии **View**.

А так же следует выполнить вот эти [рекомендации](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html). особенно обратив внимание на [оптимизацию иерархии layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) и возможные OverDraw.

На русском немного есть [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/255997/) и [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/viewstub.php).

P.S.: По вашему коду - в **doInBackground** нельзя работать с **UI** элементами.

P.S.2.: Покажите пожалуйста **xml**-разметку и код **onCreate** вашего долго грузящегося **Activity**.